# Android App incompatible with all devices on Google play

Tags: android, apk

Loaded my apk file on Google play only to find that it is not compatible with any device.  In the manifest file I support all screen sizes, build grade has a minimum sdk level of 15 and a target sdk level of 21.

The Apk file downloads on on my phone and tablet when loaded to Google drive. Nor sure if any one can help. 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.songbook.noo.sttrfsongbook"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
}

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
```

Comment: How does your Manifest look like?

Comment: You should update your build tools and gradle plugin and your Android Studio

Comment: Just checked Google play says my apk file is designed for 10 inch tablets how do I change it?

Comment: @SuperSasquatch where does it say that exactly?